# When is the Django session key generated in a Django application?

Tags: django, authentication, session, session-keys

When is the Django session key generated in a Django web application?
More precisely I don't use Django authentication system. I use an external system. I check whether a session id is present for authentication of new tab. If already exist, application will be loaded in the new tab. Else authentication process will take place. But it always show that a key is present(generated precisely). I want to know which is the exact point where the session id or key is generated(Eg: in session middleware)

Comment: Not sure about what you need.
It "happens" here:https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py#L58

But for the rest, it'll depend on your backend. If "db" is used, you might want to have a look over here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py#L80

Comment: A session is not related to whether or not a user is logged in. Anonymous users can also have a session. Maybe you should set specific session key and check whether that exists rather than checking for a session.

Comment: My scenario is that  I don't use Django authentication system. I use an external system. I want to use custom session middleware instead of session middleware/app. What should I do?